# VERR_TOO_MUCH_DATA - Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, screen

I got this problem when I saved my VM state. I saw some result on website: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12528.

Where **Darckclone** wrote: "*I am having this problem with 2D acceleration. When I start a VM with saved state, VBox drops me this error about VGA. If I remove the saved state from the VM, it starts correctly. It only happens when I enter to the VBhost using Remote Desktop and I try to start the VM. If I try it without RDP it starts perfectly with saved state.*"

So then I entered on VM on normal mode (I turned off saving VM state) and it works. But when I logged I saw that screen all the time - without any folders. Aplications on VM works correctly. Any help here?

Comment: What screen do you see all the time?

Comment: Wallpaper all the time - but there is no files or directories.